# can tensor flow using multi-cpu process?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I have a desktop computer with 4 cpu.
can I run tensorflow with 4 cpu so it is faster than single cpu ?
like a MPI programme ?
and can I use tflearn to implement it ?
thanks  very much !

Answer (score 0):

Yes tensorflow will take advantage of the multiple cores on your CPU.  When you build it from source you can build it to only run on the CPU or be able to run on both the CPU and GPU.  Right now I have tensorflow built to run on my GPU but if I want to place it on the CPU I stick the following at the top of my python code.

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''
```

This just sets an environment variable which can be done through the terminal as well.  When I run it with no cuda devices aviable it runs all cores of my CPU at 100%.  I would imagine that if you were to put this at the top of your tflearn code it would force it onto the cpu as well.

Comment: Thanks , but i put the line os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '' " on the top of my code , i see the job job running still not fully use of the CPU . i do not have GPU and I did not install CUDA.

Comment: It does not seem to max it out for me either.  If I had to guess it has to do with memory bandwidth.  Matrix operations are very heavy on the memory usage and your CPU may just spend a lot of time being inactive while waiting for memory it requested.  That is another advantage of having a GPU.  They have much higher memory bandwidth.